# How much kilometres it takes to fully set new hydraulic tappets after installing in royal enfield classic 350?

Tags: motorcycle, noise, enfield-classic, valve-lifter, royal-enfield

I just installed new hydraulic tappet set due to noisy old hydraulic tappets. 90% noise(tik-tik) is gone.
 30-40 kilometres are done after new hydraulics installation but still 10% tik tik noise can be heard. So how to make engine less noisy after getting hot ?
Push rod, cam gear, cam sleevee, 
Hydraulic tappet whole set changed recently.

Comment: Are you using the correct grade / specification of oil? Has the oil and filter been changed recently? Is the oil reaching the tappets in sufficient volume? is one of the galleries (partially) blocked?

Comment: @SolarMike i am using royal enfield liquid gun 15w-50 and changed about 1k kms

Comment: So, what do the manufacturers specify as oil for that engine?

Comment: @SolarMike its a default oil provided by royal enfield company service stations.

Answer (score 1):

Tappet noise is a "feature" provided by RE on Classic 350. While it doesn't do any harm as such, you can get the tappet rods set changed (the ones on Himalayan seem to be better : these are lengthier and have a groove). Tappet noise doesn't get better with the mileage. It gets better only with tappet rod adjustments AFAIK.